# Clean way to programmatically add attributes to a view field entity label link

Tags: views, 8

I have a View that lists entities. One of the fields is the entity label field, which is set to output a link to the entity itself. I would like to add attributes to the `<a>` tag to grab later with a jQuery plugin.

I can use `template_preprocess_views_view_field()` and `hook_views_pre_render()` to get the rendered markup and alter it there, but it's very dirty and not something I'll consider. I could also create a specific theme suggestion and field template and do it that way, but I don't want to rely on something that's potentially editable or changeable. It needs to be as generic as possible.

Is there a clean solution for this?

Comment: I would recommend you inspect element and see what the field template suggestion is. Theme that file to your needs. Editing an existing template will not add any overhead.

Comment: If you can't find this option in Views UI then the cleanest way is to install a contrib or custom field handler plugin which provides this option.

Comment: @4k4 I want to do it programmatically. A field handler seems overkill for this, since it should be as generic as possible.

Comment: By custom field handler I meant programming a field handler, but you wouldn't start from scratch, you would extend the existing handler.

Comment: After checking the existing field handlers I think you used the generic option "Link to the Entity", not a label specific one. So it might be easier to add a custom views field plugin from scratch. See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the scaffolding of a Views field plugin with Drupal Console

```
drupal generate:plugin:views:field
```

and put the link in the render() method generated by the command above:

```
  public function render(ResultRow $values) {
    if ($entity = $values->_entity) {
      return [
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#title' => $entity->label(),
        '#url' => $entity->toUrl(),
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['foo'],
        ],
      ];
    }
  }
```

After clearing the cache you'll find the new field plugin when adding a field to the FIELDS list.